# Enable a Button When any of Checkboxes on Windows is Checked

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 3 CheckBoxes on Windows. I want to enable Button When any of this CheckBoxes is Checked by using binding.  I know tips like this :

```
<Button IsEnabled={Binding ElementName=CheckBox1,Path=IsChecked} />
```

but I want button bind to other 2 CheckBox.

How to do this?

Answer (score 10):

you can use MultiBinding with a MultiValueConverter

```
<Button>
  <Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource MultiCheckedToEnabledConverter}>
      <Binding ElementName="CheckBox1" Path="IsChecked" />
      <Binding ElementName="CheckBox2" Path="IsChecked" />
      <Binding ElementName="CheckBox3" Path="IsChecked" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

```
public class MultiCheckedToEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    if (values != null) {
      return values.OfType<bool>().Any(b => b);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return new object[] {};
  }

  #endregion
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: @BalamBalam Unfortunately, this is the reality at StackOverflow. There are many users that do not show their gratitude. This is very frustrating as you put into it a long time to StackOverflow!